# Silent error while accessing Redis

Tags: redis, rust

I am a newbie with Rust. I am using the crate `redis = "0.3.1"` but the program simply exits without raising a panic. The only thing I am doing different is that the database is different.

```
extern crate redis;

use redis::*;
use std::string::String;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    read_meta_keys_redis("myset".to_string());
}

fn read_meta_keys_redis(key: String) -> redis::RedisResult<()> {
    println!("22{}", key);
    let client = try!(redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1:6379/2"));

    let con = try!(client.get_connection());
    let mems: HashSet<i32> = try!(con.smembers(key));
    for x in mems.iter() {
        println!("op-->{}", x);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Have you checked for the value of the `RedisResult` returned by `read_meta_keys_redis`?

Comment: This was cross-posted to the [Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3b9rg8/accessing_redis_from_rust/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short answer

The error is raised, but you are ignoring it.

## Long anser

Non-fatal errors are usually propagated by returning a `Result`, so the caller can handle the error. Panics are mostly used for unrecoverable errors and will abort the current thread. In this case, the redis library uses the `RedisResult` type, which is an alias for `Result<T, RedisError>`.

If you want to handle the error, you should do so by matching on the result type. Try changing your main function to the following:

```
fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = read_meta_keys_redis("myset".to_string()) {
        println!("{}", e.description());
    }
}
```

See also: [Error Handling (The Rust Book)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html)

Comment: I assumed rust bubbled up the exception trace as java does. clearly I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I am able to get the error back.  but initial objective is still unmet . I am getting the error **Invalid database number**  my local redis client says 127.0.0.1:6379[2]> smembers myset
1) "hello"
2) "how are you"
127.0.0.1:6379[2]>

Comment: Maybe you could open a new question for that. I am not familiar with redis ;)

Comment: I am from Java background, so assumed that exception gets bubbled up the execution trace. Thanks for correcting me

Comment: No problem ;)... If you are happy with the answer, you can mark it as answer so people can know that the question is solved.