# Error accessing a different Redis database using redis crate : Invalid database number

Tags: redis, rust

I am trying to access Redis using the crate `redis` (version 0.3.1). It throws **invalid database**.

```
extern crate redis;

use redis::*;
use std::string::String;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
   if let Err(e) = read_meta_keys_redis("myset".to_string()) {
     println!("{}", e.description());
   }
 }

fn read_meta_keys_redis(key: String) -> redis::RedisResult<()> {
  println!("22{}", key);
  let client = try!(redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1:6379/2"));

  let con = try!(client.get_connection());
  let mems: HashSet<i32> = try!(con.smembers(key));
  for x in mems.iter() {
      println!("op-->{}", x);
  }
  Ok(())
}
```

my local `redis`: Issue the following commands on shell
    `redis-cli
     select 2 
     sadd myset "hello"
     sadd myset "how are you"`

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> smembers myset 
  1) "hello" 2) "how are you" 
127.0.0.1:6379[2]>
```

Some background might be found in my earlier question [Silent error while accessing Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084967/silent-error-while-accessing-redis#) .

Comment: Have you checked that the details are actually correct, the server is running, the connection details are in the format expected, *&c.*? There’s nowhere near enough information here at present.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I have edited the question to post the details..

Comment: I think that @ChrisMorgan is asking that you ensure that your connection information is the same between the command line usage and the code. Specifically, it seems that the database you are selecting (`/2`) may not be correct. Please [edit] your question to include how you are invoking the `redis-cli` command.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have edited the question to be more clearer. 127.0.0.1:6379 [2]> doesn't it  denote that cli is connected to redis on DB 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is [coming from inside the crate](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/redis-rs/blob/983887b6318b25bcf84caeb02a80902277c7551a/src/connection.rs#L85-L86):

```
path => path.parse::<i64>().unwrap_or(
    fail!((ErrorKind::InvalidClientConfig, "Invalid database number"))),
```

Unfortunately, this is just a programming error. `unwrap_or` **always** evaluates the argument, which in this case is the `fail!` macro. It appears that this should be `unwrap_or_else`, which accepts a closure that is only run in the failure case.

I've [submitted a PR](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/redis-rs/pull/51) to fix the immediate issue. As a workaround, you can create a `redis::ConnectionInfo` struct directly and specify the database there.

Comment: I have taken in the local copy of the library and made the changes whatever PR made and re-ran the application. Now I am able to get past the initial hurdle and now I have  `Response was of incompatible type` error and cause is a "None". Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: @harry not really; it sounds like another question :-) My only guess is that you've said `HashSet<i32>` when your command line shows strings.

Comment: obviously I am dumb programmer :( . how could I have overlooked that blatant issue ... yeah that was the root cause. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i had one more question : the second approach by creating `redis::ConnectionInfo` struct  , I am getting : field `connection_info` of struct `redis::client::Client` is private; which is expected. is there any possibility in rust change the visibility of fields on the fly ?

Comment: *obviously I am dumb programmer* - nah, we all have to learn things at some point ^_^. *any possibility in rust change the visibility of fields on the fly* - nope, that would circumvent the reason of the visibility modifiers. Maybe that should be a separate bug report to the crate maintainer?

Comment: probably the crate maintainer never expected; whomsoever using library; to instantiate connection_info directly from calling code. I am guessing  from the pain the author had taken in incorporating the parsing logic. anyways thanks a lot!!!